# one click MUI export

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

Hello MUI datagrid react folks, I have disabled both csv and print since I only need excel. Now only excel shows but requires 2 clicks to export. One click for drop down to show then select export excel. How to make it export to excel on one click no show drop down. Thanks

I have this
<GridToolbarExport printOptions={{ disableToolbarButton: true }} csvOptions={{ disableToolbarButton: true }}/>

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the existing GridToolbar that renders as a drop-down with up to 3 sub-menu items to render.  Disabling 2 of them still leaves the Excel sub-menu item to render, thus it takes 2 clicks to enable.

You could instead create [a custom toolbar](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#custom-toolbar) with a single button that directly invokes the [Export To Excel API](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#excel).

Comment: Thanks . Any sample in the docs on how to call this on button click. The link you gave just says use below
exportDataAsExcel: (options?: GridExcelExportOptions) => Promise<void> 
Some other articles talk about getting an apiref handle etc

Comment: Found it here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150350/react-mui-datagrid-how-to-disable-menu-in-gridtoolbarexport?rq=2